# Customized HTML checkbox label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a customized check box which is grabbed from Codepen.

When the page loads the checkbox is almost checked and no text is available in the box.

[image: Click here to see checkedcheckbox].

When the user unchecks the checkbox it shows the value of its label:

[image: Click here to see unchecked checkbox].

What I want to do is to show a custom message to be displayed in the checkbox like 'Click me to confirm the contact'. When the user unchecks the checkbox it works fine showing that contacted.

I have tried with jQuery and it is not working. Could anyone give me a working solution? I expect something like this:

[image]

Thanks.

```css
.inputGroup {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.inputGroup label {
  padding: 12px 30px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  color: #3C454C;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: color 200ms ease-in;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 40px;
}

.inputGroup label:before {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  content: '';
  border: 2px solid #D1D7DC;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='32' height='32' viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.414 11L4 12.414l5.414 5.414L20.828 6.414 19.414 5l-10 10z' fill='%23fff' fill-rule='nonzero'/%3E%3C/svg%3E ");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 2px 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  background-color: green;
}

.inputGroup input:checked~label {
  color: #fff;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #5562eb;
}

.inputGroup input:checked~label:before {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(56, 56, 1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(56, 56, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: white;
}

.inputGroup input {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  order: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputGroup">
  <input id="radio1" name="radioContacted" value="contacted" type="checkbox" checked />
  <label for="radio1" id="radio01">Contacted</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really understand why you want your checkbox to be always checked ( as i see in your HTML  ) but here's a solution to change the text on the label. Using `:after` pseudo-element.

If this is not what you are looking for. Please let me know in the comments.

```css
.inputGroup {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position:relative;
}

.inputGroup label {
  padding: 12px 30px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  color: #3C454C;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: color 200ms ease-in;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.inputGroup label:before {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  content: '';
  border: 2px solid #D1D7DC;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='32' height='32' viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.414 11L4 12.414l5.414 5.414L20.828 6.414 19.414 5l-10 10z' fill='%23fff' fill-rule='nonzero'/%3E%3C/svg%3E ");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 2px 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  background-color: green;
}
.inputGroup label:after {
   content:"Contacted";
   position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   transform:translateY(-50%);
   z-index:2;
   left: 15px;
 }
 
 .inputGroup input:checked~label:after {

  content:"Click me to confirm";
 }

.inputGroup input:checked~label {
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #5562eb;
}

.inputGroup input:checked~label:before {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(56, 56, 1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(56, 56, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: white;
}

.inputGroup input {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  order: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputGroup">
  <input id="radio1" name="radioContacted" value="contacted" type="checkbox" checked />
  <label for="radio1" id="radio01"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: It would make more sense to do the opposite. "Click to confirm" when unchecked and "contacted' with the tick when checked, just switching the styles around.

Comment: yep. That;s why i said i didn't really understand his logic behind the checkbox being checked at page load ( as per his HTML ) . Yep. For that to work and to make sense, the styles should be switched

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using JavaScript to swap out the label values. One of the issues I ran into with this was that you had a text color of white on the label which I've had to remove to display the label.

```js
input = document.getElementById('radio1');
label = document.getElementById('radio01');

function handleClick() {
  (input.checked ? label.innerText = "Click me to confirm the contact" : label.innerText = "Contacted");
}

input.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

```css
.inputGroup {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#para {
  z-index: 999;
}

.inputGroup label {
  padding: 12px 30px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  color: #3C454C;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: color 200ms ease-in;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 40px;
}

.inputGroup label:before {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  content: '';
  border: 2px solid #D1D7DC;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='32' height='32' viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.414 11L4 12.414l5.414 5.414L20.828 6.414 19.414 5l-10 10z' fill='%23fff' fill-rule='nonzero'/%3E%3C/svg%3E ");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 2px 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  background-color: green;
}

.inputGroup input:checked~label {
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #5562eb;
}

.inputGroup input:checked~label:before {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(56, 56, 1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(56, 56, 1);
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.inputGroup input {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  order: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputGroup">
  <input id="radio1" name="radioContacted" value="contacted" type="checkbox" checked />
  <label for="radio1" id="radio01">Click me to confirm the contact</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear @mihai  your answer is working fine for my requirement. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Dear @Andy  your answer also working fine for my requirement. Thanks for the help

Comment: Dear @mistermansam I agree with you . But this system was build previously like this.If I try to change it need to change number of files . So it would be preffer like this.However thank you very much for commenting.Thanks.